# SimpleDateFormat doesn't maintain timezone

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat

i have a date object in the following format:

**Sun Jan 20 10:12:27 GMT+02:00 2013**

the above time appears in microsoft outlook correctly:

**Sun 1/20/2013 12:12 PM** (this is the time in GMT+2 >> client timezone)

when trying to format the date object with `SimpleDateFormat` to appear as in the outlook, using the following code:

```java
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat(
    "EEE M/d/yyyy hh:mm a");
    String receivedDate = sdf.format(email.getDateTimeReceived());
```

the result of formatting is:

**Sun 1/20/2013 10:12 AM**

so the two hours of the timezone difference are missing.

please advise how to fix that, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to format the date using the GMT time zone.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE M/d/yyyy hh:mm a");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);
```

Comment: i want to format the date to the user timezone as in outlook.

Comment: Then pass the user's timezone instead of GMT.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to tell to the `SimpleDateFormat` to include the timezone information.

This will do the trick:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat(
    "EEE M/d/yyyy hh:mm a zzzZ yyyy");
```

Note the Uppercase `Z` at the end to display the time diff

This will print:

> Sun 1/20/2013 12:09 PM CET+0100 2013

if you need it to be GMT you can force that like this:

```
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

Now it will print:

> Sun 1/20/2013 11:11 AM GMT+0000 2013

if you don't need the AM/PM just remove the `a`